# Perl command line search and replace with multiple expressions

Tags: perl

I am using Perl to search and replace multiple regular expressions:
When I execute the following command, I get an error:

```
prompt> find "*.cpp" | xargs perl -i -pe 's/##(\W)/\1/g' -pe 's/(\W)##/\1/g'
syntax error at -e line 2, near "s/(\W)##/\1/g"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
xargs: perl: exited with status 255; aborting
```

Having multiple `-e` is valid in Perl, then why is this not working? Is there a solution to this?

Comment: You could replace those two regexes with an alternation: `s/##(?=\W)|(?<=\W)##//g`

Comment: @TLP I am a noob to Perl; please can you explain what does the ?= and ?<= mean this context?

Comment: They are look-around assertions, you can read more about them in [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Look-Around-Assertions). They are zero-width, so they only check, and do not remove.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Several `-e`'s are allowed.

You are missing the `';'`

```
find "*.cpp" | xargs perl -i -pe 's/##(\W)/\1/g;' -pe 's/(\W)##/\1/g;'
```

Perl statements has to end with `;`. 
Final statement in a block doesn't need a terminating semicolon. 
So a single `-e` without `;` will work, but you will have to add `;` when you have multiple `-e` statements.

Comment: Or `xargs perl -i -pe 's/##(\W)/\1/g  ;  s/(\W)##/\1/g;'`

Comment: Perl's `;` isn't a statement terminator. It's a statement separator. You only need it when you want to start a new statement to follow a previous one. That's why you can leave it off the final statement in a scope.

Comment: The relevant documentation: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#-e-commandline

The [`-p` option](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#-p) just places the `while (<>)` loop around your "program", which is constructed by concatenating all the `-e` options.

Answer (score 2):

Having multiple `-e` values are valid, but is it useful? The values from the multiple `-e` are merely combined into one program, and it's up to you to ensure that together they make a syntactically correct program. The `B::Deparse` program can show you what `perl` thinks the program is:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e 'print' -e 'q(Hello'  -e ')'
print "Hello\n";
-e syntax OK
```

A curious thing to note is that a newline snuck in there. Think about how it got there to see what else `perl` is doing to combine multiple `-e` values.

In your program, you are substituting on the current line, then taking the modified line and substituting again. That's better written as:

```
prompt> find "*.cpp" | xargs perl -i -pe 's/##(\W)/\1/g; s/(\W)##/\1/g'
```

Now, if you are building up this command line by adding more and more `-e` through some automated process and you don't know ahead of time what you get, maybe those `-e` make sense. However, you might consider that you can do the same thing to build up the string you give to `-e`. I don't know what might be better because you didn't explain why you are doing it that way.

But, I suspect that in some cases, people are actually thinking about having only one substitution work. They want to try one and if its pattern doesn't work, try a different one until one succeeds. In that case you don't want to separate the substitutions by semicolons. Use the short-circuiting `||` instead. The `s///` returns the number of substitutions it made and `||` will stop (short circuit) when it finds a true value:

```
prompt> find "*.cpp" | xargs perl -i -pe 's/##(\W)/\1/g || s/(\W)##/\1/g'
```

And note, you only need one `-p`. It only does its job once. Here's the program with multiple `-p` deparsed:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -i -pe 's/##(\W)/\1/g;' -pe 's/(\W)##/\1/g;'
BEGIN { $^I = ""; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = readline ARGV)) {
    s/##(\W)/$1/g;
    s/(\W)##/$1/g;
}
continue {
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}
-e syntax OK
```

It's the same thing as having only one `-p`:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -pi -e 's/##(\W)/\1/g;' -e 's/(\W)##/\1/g;'
BEGIN { $^I = ""; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = readline ARGV)) {
    s/##(\W)/$1/g;
    s/(\W)##/$1/g;
}
continue {
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}
-e syntax OK
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks so much!  You helped me reduce my ascii / decimal / 8-bit binary table printer enough to fit in a tweet:

```
for i in {32..126};do printf "'\x$(printf %x $i)'(%3i) = " $i; printf '%03o\n' $i | perl \
-pe 's#0#000#g;' -pe 's#1#001#g;' -pe 's#2#010#g;' -pe 's#3#011#g;' \
-pe 's#4#100#g;' -pe 's#5#101#g;' -pe 's#6#110#g;' -pe 's#7#111#g' ; done | \
perl -pe 's#= 0#= #'
```

Comment: You don't need to work so hard: `seq 32 126 | perl -ne 'printf qq{\x27%s\x27(%3d) = %b\n}, chr($_), $_, $_'`